# Installation problem on Laravel - cURL error 52: Empty reply from server

Tags: php, laravel, curl, installation

TLTR:

```
In CurlFactory.php line 200:

  cURL error 52: Empty reply from server (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/
  libcurl-errors.html)
```

I'm new in using Laravel and I'm trying different approaches.

One of the is to following the Laracast lessons on https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-6-from-scratch .

There's a problem though. My wish is to install Laravel globally and I'm doing through Composer.

My php version is 7.3.11, mysql 8.0.18, I installed them through homebrew (last version) and only then I tried to install laravel through composer.

I downloaded composer:

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'a5c698ffe4b8e849a443b120cd5ba38043260d5c4023dbf93e1558871f1f07f58274fc6f4c93bcfd858c6bd0775cd8d1') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

And then I installed it globally because I moved the composer.phar file

`mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`

Last thing, I installed laravel globally

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

and then I added a path to the /etc/paths files through vim

```
/Users/myselfuser/.composer/vendor/bin

sudo vim /etc/paths
```

and I did everything through my terminal.

Everything seems to work but the problem is that, if I tried to create a new project, I receive the error at the very beginning (cURL error 52), but I tried to find something regarding the problem and I didn't find anything about this error.

To summirize, I'm able to create a project with:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel my-laravel-project
```

but not with:

```
laravel new my-laravel-project
```

Does anyone have the same problem?

Comment: I have the same issue running PHP 7.4, Laravel 7, and Laravel installer 3.0.1.  I am on macos Catalina 10.15.3. and running Laravel Valet 2.8.1 as my dev environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using Homebrew make sure to stop your services (brew services stop httpd) before creating the laravel project (laravel new my-laravel-project)

Answer (score -1):

I solve same problem
I have running local server (php artisan serve)
"laravel new" finish success when I stop local server